# Android: app won't go home after home button press on some devices

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I am developing an Android app. When the app is running in the emulator or on my Moto 4G or the Google Pixel and I press the home button, I am going home (as expected).

However, when I run the app on an Acer E380 and I press the home button, nothing happens, although other apps on the same mobile phone don't have this issue.

The emulator, Moto 4G and Acer E380 are running on Android 4.4.2.

I have no code that tries to detect a home button press.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: I would recommend going through `adb` logs. You could gather more information about the issue in the logs

Answer (score 0):

have you using below code ?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
       //The Code Want to Perform. 
    }
});
```

Comment: No, I haven't. As far as I know, Android should simply go home when I press the home button, and I should not have to write any code to do so.

Besides, the home button is working perfectly on the emulator, the Moto 4G and the Google Pixel. It's simply not working on the Acer E380.